# svg background rotating differently in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, svg

I`m trying to create cross browser polaroid effect using svg images as picture backround as seen here 
http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/svg/gallery.php

If you are using IE9 you should notice problem at first look - the svg background rotates differently in IE. Problem appears only in IE and seems to be related with background-size property. If I toggle in IE background size and rotate propertys, IE starts to show everything correctly!

does anybody have solution to this problem?

CSS I`m using for moment:

```
.image img {

    border: 0px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:275px;
    background: url(/test/images/polaroid.svg);
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100% ;
    margin: 25px auto 45px 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:4% 5.5% 6% 4%;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);

}
```

I am talking only about IE9 here! For 7 and 8 I´m using progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix

Answer (score 0):

If you use SVG as background - so you can do all internal pictures on SVG. 
For IE8- use [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/).

For rotations use `transform="rotate(-30)"` on `<image>` inside SVG.

So, in every `<li>` you will have SVG. And it will be working equally
 in all browsers.